# awk getline to display first three lines in file

Tags: awk, scripting

I'm using

```
awk 'BEGIN {while((getline gf < "awk.script") > 0) {print gf}}'
```

to read me first 3 three lines of the pattern. I can do with  `head -3` . But I don't want to since, I have to switch lines between two files.

Suppose awk.script contains

```
line 1
line 2
line 3 <------- until here
line 4
```

I have tried updating the original cmd with this

```
 awk 'BEGIN {while((getline gf < "awk.script") > 0) && f{print $gf;f=0};NR<=3{f=1}}'
```

the code is influenced from the examples give on link:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern

error i'm getting is

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {while((getline gf < "awk.script") > 0) f{print $gf;f=0};NR<=3{f=1}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {while((getline gf < "awk.script") > 0) f{print $gf;f=0};NR<=3{f=1}}
awk: cmd. line:1:
```

How can it be done? thanks

Comment: Getline has to be in the `BEGIN` clause?

Comment: Cross posted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511981/awk-getline-to-display-first-three-lines-in-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use getline, but if that is what you need:

```
echo|awk 'BEGIN {while((getline gf < "awk.script") > 0) {print gf; if(++i > 2) break;}}'
```

You could get the same behaviour like this:

```
awk 'NR>3{exit} {print $0}' input.txt
```

In yout attempt, two things were wrong:
NR does not get incremented with `getline`, and the and operator `&&` should not be used between the `while` clause and its code block. Your checking of `f` does not look appropriated.

Comment: thanks a lot can you explain use of `++i >2.`

Comment: In `awk`, variables are initialized with zero, so `++i` will increment a variable (which at first does not exist, so it is zero), and in every loop of the `while`, `i` will get incremented, till it reaches 3, then it breaks the loop.